# insert session for each user ip address not on each page load?

Tags: php, mysql

i am creating a unique 10 digit number, which will act as a session id whilst a user is using my site. My site has an index page with 4 different links, that link of to a new page where there is a form for the user to complete. The idea is that if a user completes a form then this form will be stored and saved under that user's unique session id. Then once the user submits the form they are taken back to the index page where upon completion of the form i echo out a div inside of that users uniqe session, the div is basically a tick icon next to the form which they have completed.

Currently i am storing a session into my database when a user lands on the home page, upon each page load, the problem here is each time a user might refresh the page, the session id is changing and a new session id is being stored. However i want the user to be able to go from one page, to another and back whilst on my site and still have the same session id from when they first landed on the index page of my site.

My question is, can i store my session id based on the user IP address or something similar, so that even if the user refreshes the page then the session id is the same?

Or can a session be set for the entire time in which a browser window is open? like a cookie or something similar

So get the users ip address and insert this as the session ID and then all the while they are on my site the site checks their IP against the database and displays the relevant ticks for the forms which have been completed?

Here's my current code, can someone please show me how i could change it to do what i need it to, thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'hewden1'; 
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password)    
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database)   
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$randnum = rand(1111111111,9999999999);


$sql="INSERT INTO supplier_session (session_number)
VALUES ('$randnum')";

$result = mysql_query($sql); 
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you just get the session id? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php - that way it will remain the same and won't be a generate on load number.

Comment: why on earth would you try to rewrite php's session support?

Comment: @giorgio that isn't aimed at me right?

Comment: @MarkP ah no, I was slow typing, didn't see your comment ;) was aimed at the poster ofcourse (although I should've posted a link as you did)